# Unable to run pytest on Mac due to permission issues

Tags: macos, pip, pytest

On Mac OS 10.14 (Mojave) I used:

```
pip install -U pytest
```

to install pytest. I got a permission denied error trying to install the packages to `/Users/nagen/Library/Python/2.7`

I tried

```
sudo pip install -U pytest
```

This time it installed successfully
But, despite adding the full path, the terminal doesn't recognize pytest.

If I try to run `/Users/nagen/Library/Python/2.7/bin/pytest` - I get permission error.
In addtion, `sudo /Users/nagen/Library/Python/2.7/bin/pytest` works, but it prompts for a password, so I can not use it in automation scripts.

Tried installing python3 and then running pip3 install...same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option might be to use a python virtual env. https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/ is a good starting point

```
> virtualenv env
> source env/bin/activate
> pip install pytest
> pytest
```

This will avoid pathing and permissions issues and keep your environment clean. From any other changes you make withing that venv.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I am not even able to install virtualenv. Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/nagen/Library/Python/3.7'
Check the permissions.

Comment: @Nagen run it as `sudo` or you can `chmod` that user DIR to give your user permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I would **strongly** recommend using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).  This is the **best** dev tool there is for mac users and I never install things without it.

To install it run the following in terminal:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Now to install python3 you simply:

```
brew install python3
```

brew will make sure your PATH is configured correctly and you shouldn't have any issues running `pip3 install x`.

Also, if you decide to reinstall python using homebrew, you will need to follow [this](https://osxuninstaller.com/uninstall-guides/properly-uninstall-python-mac/) guide to uninstall python first.  This will be the most tedious part of the process.

Make sure that you **don't** uninstall python2 packages!  Your mac OS uses them.  If you don't have python3 installed at all you can skip the uninstall step and go straight to `brew install python3`

When I first started using python, I had the same problem you are having because I tried manually installing it from python.org, then I came across homebrew and never had problems since.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I already use brew - but did not install python with brew. So, took your suggestion and tried it - got this error. Linking /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.18.0... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/git

Comment: Honestly, you should probably just reinstall your os.  You could potentially spend hours looking for answers on this (I'm guessing you already have).  A clean install should take 30 minutes or so, and if you `brew install` **everything**, you shouldn't have any problems like this again.